# Audiere library & Sound FX's, how are they enabled?

Tags: c++, audio

Does anyone can point me to a good reference/tutorial on how to add  pink noise generation effect (or any of the kind) to an OutputStream or whatever object is necessary to make it work with the Audiere library.

So far I can only play and change pan, pitch effects for a sound object, but no clue about the rest of the FX's.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fine, this should do the job if a pink noise is what you want

```
audiere::OutputStreamPtr pSample = audiere::OpenSound(m_pAudiereDevice, "getout.ogg", audiere::MULTIPLE, audiere::FF_OGG);
pSample->setVolume(0.5f);
pSample->play();

audiere::SoundEffectPtr pSoundEffect = audiere::OpenSoundEffect(m_pAudiereDevice, audiere::CreatePinkNoise(), audiere::SINGLE );
pSoundEffect->play();
```